# What is the significance of the Greek "ὅτι" as used in the original text of 1 Thessalonians 5:2?

Tags: greek, grammar, 1-thessalonians, word-choice

1 Thessalonians 5:1-2 reads as follows:

> Περὶ δὲ τῶν χρόνων καὶ τῶν καιρῶν, ἀδελφοί, οὐ χρείαν ἔχετε ὑμῖν γράφεσθαι,
> αὐτοὶ γὰρ ἀκριβῶς οἴδατε **ὅτι** ἡμέρα κυρίου ὡς κλέπτης ἐν νυκτὶ οὕτως ἔρχεται.

Or, in the New International Version (N.I.V.):

> Now, brothers and sisters, about times and dates we do not need to write to you,
> for you know very well that the day of the Lord will come like a thief in the night.

I'm trying to better understand the way that this verse is relating the verb and the noun. Why is this conjunction used in this verse and how would that be different from similar conjunctions?

Comment: It simply means "that".

Answer (score 1):

BDAG lists five functions for this often used (1309 times) conjunction ὅτι (hoti), namely:

1. **marker of narrative discourse content , direct or indirect, *that***
2. **marker of explanatory clauses, *that***
3. **marker introducing direct discourse**, in this case it is not to be rendered into English, but to be represented by quotation marks
4. **marker of causality, *because, since***
5. special uses

In 1 Thess 5:2 we have two distinct clauses:

- For you yourselves fully know
- the day of the Lord comes in this manner as a thief in the night

These two clauses are joined by the conjunction, ὅτι (hoti), which must be translated, "that" in English, ie, #2 above.  There is little mystery about this construction as it is extremely common in the NT.